# Can not print from java to jmeter - double variable scenario

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, jmeter

I am having an issue with jmeter when I try to print to log from eclipse.
I try to perform a method and print its value, the value is stored in double variable and get exception in jmeter.
no exception in eclipse just in jmeter

I checked what I send from jmeter and it is string offer id , int 0, int 0
I used:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

the function is:

```
public double get_actual_sensitivity(String Offerid,int suspicius_blocked,int suspicius_not_blocked)
    {
        double sensitivity_results = 0 ;

        if(suspicius_blocked == 0 && suspicius_not_blocked == 0) {
            return sensitivity_results;
        }
        else{
        sensitivity_results = ((double)suspicius_blocked /((double)suspicius_blocked + (double)suspicius_not_blocked ))* 100;
        //sensitivity_results = (sensitivity_results * 100);
        logger.error("The actual percantage that blocked for offer "+ Offerid  +" are: " + sensitivity_results);
        return sensitivity_results;
        }
    }
```

the exception that I get is

```
Problem in JSR223 script Get actual sensitivity for offer ${Expected_Offer_Id}, message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.error() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Double) values: [0.0]
Possible solutions: error(java.lang.String), error(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;), error(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), error(java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable), error(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String), error(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.error() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Double) values: [0.0]
Possible solutions: error(java.lang.String), error(java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;), error(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), error(java.lang.String, java.lang.Throwable), error(org.slf4j.Marker, java.lang.String), error(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:158) ~[groovy-all-2.4.12.jar:2.4.12]
```

can someone please advise?

Comment: Have you tried enabling annotation processing in your IDE?

Comment: JMeter have its own logging, do you want to print in JMeter and if not how is it connected to JMeter?

Comment: I use this to write from eclipse into Jmeter logs. I have done this for all of my functions, writing complex scenario in java, and call them from jmeter. this is the only time I am facing this issue

Comment: Tip only: `logger.error("The actual percentage that blocked for offer {} are: {}", Offerid, sensitivity_results);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to solve this issue
Double sens_res = sensitivity_results;
and print sens_res.

Answer (score 0):

To write to JMeter log always prefer JMeter own logging system, Use

```
log.error("The actual percentage that blocked for offer "+ Offerid  +" are: " + sensitivity_results);
```

You import the wrong Logger, check [JSR223](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) log, you should import the following:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
```

It's found in slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar in JMeter library.

Comment: Hey user7294900, can you please provide a link for download this jar, all I see is zip with all files regards

Comment: It's found in slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar in JMeter library.

Comment: Hey user7294900  when I import that jar and write the code private final Logger slf4jLogger = Logger.getLogger(myclass.class);   eclipse not recognize the get logger function, do yo have any step by step solution?   this is what I write import org.slf4j.Logger;     and than created a logger that I can not use since getLogger is undefined for type Logger